# check through a list for a specific value that keeps appearing in Python

Tags: python

I'm doing a project involving an accelerometer and arduino. I'm using Python on the laptop side of things. The accelerometer sends lots of bytes to the laptop. My code so far is to take the first 100 bytes and put them into a list.

```
my_list = []

data = ser.read(100)

for n in data:

    n = ser.read(size=1)
    y = int.from_bytes(n,byteorder='big')
    my_list.append(y)
```

I know that the one number (48) appears frequently and i want the next six numbers after 48. So:

```
if 48 in my_list:

    my_list.index(48)
    x0 = my_list[(my_list.index(48))+1]
    x1 = my_list[(my_list.index(48))+2]
    y0 = my_list[(my_list.index(48))+3]
    y1 = my_list[(my_list.index(48))+4]
    z0 = my_list[(my_list.index(48))+5]
    z1 = my_list[(my_list.index(48))+6]
```

This is fine but I need a way so that once this is done it continues through the list to the next 48 and repeats the process. And keeps doing this until the end of the list. 
Can anybody help? I think using iter function might work but not sure how to use it for this particularly?

Comment: can 48 appear in those six numbers?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a generator:

```
def generate_coordinates(lst, size=6):
    for i in lst:
        if lst[i] == 48:
            yield lst[i + 1: i + 1 + size]
```

And use it like this:

```
for coordinates in generate_coordinates(my_list):
    x0, x2, y0, y1, z0, z1 = coordinates
    # .. do stuff with x, y, z ...
```

Comment: You will get an error trying to use the elements to index, if you have 100  in my_list and it has 50 items then it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.islice`:

```
my_list = [1,2,48,1,2,3,4,5,6,48,1,2,3,4,5,6]

from itertools import islice
for ind, ele in enumerate(my_list):
    if ele == 48:
        a, b, c, d, e, f = islice(my_list, ind+1, ind+7)
        print(a,b,c,d,e,f)
1 2 3 4 5 6
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

You should also probably use a try/except because if you have 48 in any of the last 6 elements you will get an error as you cannot get 6 items after if there are less than 7 items left:

```
for ind, ele in enumerate(my_list):
    if ele == 48:
        try:
            a, b, c, d, e, f = islice(my_list, ind+1, ind+7)
            print(a, b, c, d,e, f)
        except ValueError:
            pass
```